# Should I add middle-school achievements to my resume, as a person who attends high school?

Tags: resume

Will potential employers be interested in any of my achievements from 8th grade, as someone who attends high school?

I am sixteen years old.

In eighth grade, I received highest honors in mathematics and I was a member of the National Honor Society.

I am applying to be a cashier.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78364/discussion-on-question-by-cmk-should-i-add-middle-school-achievements-to-my-resu).

Answer (score 10):

> Will potential employers be interested in any of my achievements from 8th grade

No

Comment: Here is a classic example where a one word answer actually works.  :-)

Comment: I don;t even know an employer that would hire a youngster as cashier unknown, let alone one that would be interested in 2 year old schoolwork

Comment: @Kilisi I worked at a fast-food place, including manning the cash register, when I was 16.  This was pretty common among my cohort.

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"Yes"_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Answer (score 5):

Yes, put it on your resume.

Here are three questions do decide should you put something on your resume?

1. Will this information help give the message that you are a good fit for the job?

Possibly. Some store managers may decide to win such a reward you a hard worker or that you are reliable or that you are smart. If they don’t think any of these I still think it doesn’t hurt.

2. Is this something you are willing to talk about if asked?

I hope so.

3. Will this make your resume too long?

For a 16-year-old, I doubt it.